# Why Monix Observable produces one element more than needed

Tags: scala, stream, reactive-streams, monix

I'm playing with Monix streams and got the example where I build `Observable` from `Iterator`. It seems to me like when run it produces 1 more element than I'd expect. The following code shows that:

```
  val count = AtomicLong(0)
  def produceValue(): Long = {
    count.transformAndGet { i =>
      logger.info(s"Producing value: ${i + 1}")
      i + 1
    }
  }
  def more(): Boolean = count.get < 20

  lazy val iter = new Iterator[Long] {
    override def hasNext: Boolean = more()
    override def next(): Long     = produceValue()
  }    

  Observable
    .fromIterator(iter)
    .mapParallelUnordered(5) { x =>
      Task(x)
        .foreachL { x =>
          logger.info(s"Transforming $x")
        }
        .delayExecution(3.seconds)
    }
    .consumeWith(Consumer.complete)
    .runAsync
```

The case is quite simple. There is `Iterator` that prints log every time it produces a `next` value. Downstream stage is simple delayed task run in parallel count of 5 to see what's happening. Now the output is as follows:

```
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [main] -  Producing value: 1
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [main] -  Producing value: 2
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [main] -  Producing value: 3
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [main] -  Producing value: 4
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [main] -  Producing value: 5
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [main] -  Producing value: 6
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-19] -  Transforming 4
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-22] -  Transforming 3
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-20] -  Transforming 5
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-21] -  Transforming 2
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-18] -  Transforming 1
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-26] -  Producing value: 7
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-26] -  Producing value: 8
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-26] -  Producing value: 9
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-26] -  Producing value: 10
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-26] -  Producing value: 11
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-22] -  Transforming 7
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-20] -  Transforming 6
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-21] -  Transforming 9
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-26] -  Transforming 8
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-17] -  Transforming 10
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-20] -  Producing value: 12
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-20] -  Producing value: 13
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-20] -  Producing value: 14
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-20] -  Producing value: 15
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-20] -  Producing value: 16
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-17] -  Transforming 11
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-27] -  Transforming 13
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-20] -  Transforming 12
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-19] -  Transforming 14
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-26] -  Transforming 15
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-18] -  Producing value: 17
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-18] -  Producing value: 18
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-18] -  Producing value: 19
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-18] -  Producing value: 20
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-20] -  Transforming 16
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-18] -  Transforming 20
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-27] -  Transforming 18
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-17] -  Transforming 19
[INFO ] c.s.f.a.t.MonixSandbox$ [scala-execution-context-global-19] -  Transforming 17
```

As you can see, initially the stream produces 6 elements while I'd expect 5 only (as the downstream stage `mapParallelUnordered` takes only 5 elements. Actually that's not a big deal, but I just want to understand why is it so.

Also why the initial values are produced in `main` thread while subsequent ones are invoked on `execution-context` thread pool? Shouldn't all be using scheduler that is used to run entire stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you can see, initially the stream produces 6 elements

The low-level communication protocol is designed around a `Subscriber` and its (inherited) method onNext with the following signature:

```
def onNext(elem: A): Future[Ack]
```

[(source)](https://github.com/monix/monix/blob/v3.0.0-RC2/monix-reactive/shared/src/main/scala/monix/reactive/Observer.scala#L48)

If we picture creation and transformation each being a stage, the source observable (`fromIterator` in your case) *pushes* its value down to subscribers, and, when acknowledged, pushes the next one.

So what happens is:

- `fromIterator` stage generates value 1
- the 1 value is pushed to `mapAsyncUnordered` stage, where it is accepted (b/c there are free workers), so the acknowledgement is to immediately `Continue`
- Above steps are repeated for values 2-5
- `fromIterator` stage generates value 6 (this is when you see the output)
- the 6 value is pushed to `mapAsyncUnordered` stage. This time, it cannot be accepted immediately, so the acknowledgement is to `Continue` some time later. Until that, no more values are generated by `fromIterator`.

What's to note is that it's not `mapAsyncUnordered` stage that pulls the value out of `fromIterator`, but that `fromIterator` generates these values on its own, and it cannot know in advance if the downstream transformation will accept the value immediately or not.

---

> Shouldn't all be using scheduler that is used to run entire stream?

Monix Observable tries to work synchronously as much as possible for performance reasons (switching threads is expensive). In general, unless controlled explicitly by methods like `executeAsync`, `executeOn`, etc., you won't be able to tell whether operation will execute on same thread or not.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it's more like the item is not produced until there is a demand from downstream, not that it stays ready to be pushed